# Fix lines in volumetric in EEVEE

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, shadows, volumetrics

I render space scene in EEVEE. Density is 0,01. Scene have two light - fill sun and blick point.
And in scene I have this lines. I up all samples, but dont have clean pic. What i do wrong?
[settings, shadows is 64 px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyRD4.png)

[image: lines on the planet]

Comment: soft shadows are allowed? 16 render samples is really low, did you try with 100+ samples if it is still the same result?

Comment: yes, and nothing changes.

Comment: fixed - 256 sampls EEVEE, 128 volume